# Git workflow with Octopress on Heroku

Tags: git, heroku, octopress

I want to deploy an Octopress blog on Heroku. The problem is that this requires to add the "public" directory (containing the compiled stuff) under VCS. But for my general workflow I don't want to track this directory. So what can should I do to:

1. Track the changes to source and config files and push this to GitHub.
2. Push the generated blog to Heroku.
3. Keep Octopress updatable (see http://octopress.org/docs/updating/)

I am new to Heroku and Octopress, so please be detailed in your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard method for deploying Octopress to heroku is to commit and deploy the public directory. I agree that this isn't ideal because tracking generated assets is generally a bad practice. However, since this is a static site, being able to deploy static assets makes it easier to deploy your blog anywhere since you won't depend on a remote server being configured to generate your blog for you.

That being said, there are some folks who are pioneering with build-packs and Heroku's cedar stack. You can follow their work here. http://jasongarber.com/blog/2012/01/10/deploying-octopress-to-heroku-with-a-custom-buildpack

I haven't attempted this method but many have reported success using it. If you have trouble, please contact the author as I'm sure they will be more able to assist you.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. I assume I'm better off using GitHub Pages? Octopress seems intended for GH, while deploying on Heroku is more a hack than a clean solution for me :)

Comment: Github pages, or Rsync to an ssh supporting web host are probably better solutions.

Comment: @schlamar Using custom buildpacks on Heroku really isn't a hack. It's actually quite powerful, and not too hard if you're willing to spend a couple of hours sorting it out. I've used custom buildpacks for fairly large client projects, and they worked out very well.

Comment: @redhotvengeance Yes, but I have to hack in Octopress to get it running. Not talking about buildpacks in general ;)

Comment: @schlamar Ah. Yeah, I built my blog using vanilla Jekyll, not Octopress, so I wasn't aware that they fine-tuned things that would need to be undone when building on deploy.